# How to convert a Matrix4 to a Matrix3 in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

Does anyone know how to convert a Matrix4 to a Matrix3 in ThreeJS?

I am trying to get the 'inverse view rotation' matrix. From what I understand you need to do something like this:

1) convert the camera.matrixWorldInverse to a Matrix3 
2) Then invert the result

Is that correct? And if so, how would I convert from a Matrix4 to 3?

Thanks for any help all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the inversion on the 4x4 matrix. The upper 3x3 will contain the inverse rotation that you want. Otherwise use the set method of the 3x3 matrix and assign it the values of your 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Thanks gaitat. Do you mean like this: `var viewInv = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse( camera.matrixWorldInverse );
 var e = viewInv.elements;
 var viewRot = new THREE.Matrix3().set(
  e[0],e[1],e[2], 
  e[4],e[5],e[6], 
  e[8],e[9],e[10]
 ); 
 this.screenQuad.material.uniforms["inv_proj"].value = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse( camera.projectionMatrix );
 this.screenQuad.material.uniforms["inv_view_rot"].value = viewRot;`

Comment: Im basically trying to follow this tutorial: [link](http://codeflow.org/entries/2011/apr/13/advanced-webgl-part-2-sky-rendering/). Particularly the "Eye Ray" section - I don't know how to get the 2 uniforms "inv_proj" & "inv_view_rot"

Comment: Well now you are asking a different question which I am not prepared to answer as I have not played with three.js shaders enough to know which matrix corresponds to which. But I see a problem with the code above. Since matrixWorldInverse contains the inverse, why are you computing it again. Also WebGL does not have a viewMatrix as the code you are trying to follow requires. Instead it has combined the modelMatrix and the viewMatrix into the modeViewMatrix. You can see this post http://webglfactory.blogspot.gr/2011/06/how-to-create-view-matrix.html to see how to compute just the view matrix.

Comment: Thanks gaitat - I'll have to look into it further